# Remote mySQL connection error

Tags: php, mysql

I posted this question earlier but only provided a link to the output instead of posting the output here. With the additional details, I trust there will be enough info.

This script works locally on my server but when loaded on a remote server the error shown after the code below is given... Can someone tell me why it works locally and not remotely. A % wildcard has been set for allowed hosts.

```
<?php

$version_link = mysql_connect('gjinternetsolutions.com', 'gj_Guest', 'Password1');
mysql_select_db("gj_Software", $version_link);
if (mysql_errno())
{ 
    $error = "<p>MySQL error ".mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error()."\n</p>";
    die($error);
} 


$version_query = "SELECT * FROM `VersionCheck` where `Software`='RedemptionFee'";

$version_result = mysql_query($version_query);
$version_row = mysql_fetch_array($version_result);

if (mysql_errno())
{ 
    $error = "<p>MySQL error ".mysql_errno().": ".mysql_error()."\n<br>When executing:<br>\n$version_query\n</p>";
    die($error);
} 

$new_version=$version_row['Version'];
$new_URL=$version_row['URL'];

echo "The latest version of the Redemption Fee Module is: ".$new_version;

?>
```

This is the error that is given from the above script...

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'gjinternetsolutions.com' (4) in /home/nicedayh/public_html/CheckRemoteMySQL.php on line 3

Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/nicedayh/public_html/CheckRemoteMySQL.php on line 4
MySQL error 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'gjinternetsolutions.com' (4)
```

At first I thought something was wrong with my script but after seeing it work perfectly on the local machine, I am not certain. Several people have tried loading it remotely and had no success so it is not just one remote machine that has an issue.

Comment: MySQL Workbench here connects successfully to your MySQL server, and I successfully logged in with the credentials you helpfully posted above. Check your connectivity: can you actually see the server at that address? `Ping` should tell you.

Comment: Here is my problem... I personally only have access to the server hosting the database. The above script runs perfectly on that server... http://gjinternetsolutions.com/home/modules/addons/RedemptionFee/CheckRemoteMySQL.php however, 13 people that I have given the script to are all unable to get the same result as me... they all get the result mentioned above. I guess I need to understand more how you got it to work.

Comment: I haven't done anything clever. In fact I've barely done anything at all. I logged in to your MySQL server with MySQL Workbench using the PC I use every day - no problem. I placed your script, unmodified, on my development server on my office network and ran it - no problem. I placed it on one of my production servers in Chicago, still unmodified, and ran it there - again, no problem. Whatever problem your people are seeing, it's neither the script nor your server. More...

Comment: That said, I wouldn't tackle this this way. Having people log directly into a database server to retrieve one small piece of information is overkill. Why not just run this script on your server and give people the URL?

Comment: @MikeW The code supplied is not the end product. The code supplied is only sample code supplied to test the connection because my end product was not working. I simplified the code for the sake of proving it was not any other code that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to put `:3306` after your database location or whatever port your MySQL is on

Comment: This is not necessary if the server is using port 3306, unless your php.ini overrides your mysql.default_port setting.

Comment: I can only test on the the local machine as I do not have access to any remote machines; however, it works with or without the `:3306`

Comment: As a side note, if I specify a bogus port, it does not work; therefore, it is safe to say that the default port of `3306` is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to ping gjinternetsolutions.com?

My server in New Zealand recognises this host name, however my server in the US does not. Your A records may have not propagated to your computer yet, or your name servers NS1.GJINTERNETSOLUTIONS.COM and NS2.GJINTERNETSOLUTIONS.COM might be having issues.

Comment: There have been no changes to the DNS settings for the domain in over a few months. Don't think it is a propagation issue. Also, I am able to ping the domain from here in Canada... the server is in the US.

Answer (score 0):

A. Is your mysql database listening on the same server/IP that `gjinternetsolutions.com`  is hosted on since that is what you are using to connect to?

B. If it is, is `mysql service` running on the db server?

C. If it is, is port `3306` open on the `firewall` to let traffic through?

D. If it is, is your `my.cnf` file on the db server set to localhost only using `bind-address = 127.0.0.1?`  If so, comment that out.

E. If it's not, do you have mysql database setup to accept connections from a remote server i.e. not localhost?

http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely

or if you use a cpanel 
http://my.kualo.com/knowledgebase/1059-how-to-set-your-whm-server-to-use-a-remote-mysql-server.html

One of these is probably the issue. This at least should get somewhere to look.

Comment: None of these apply. See my comment above.

Comment: @MikeW not necessarily, depending on the web server it could still be a firewall issue. I've seen a web server not allow incoming connections on the server until explicitly opened. It doesn't have to be the db server that's rejecting. We don't know what server his application is on.

Comment: Well, here is my problem with the above... The server hosting the database is running on a shared server at Host Gator. That being said, I personally have limited access to verify stuff myself. After almost 2 hours working with Host Gator support, they claim that everything is good on their end. I am still confused though why it only works on the local machine.

Comment: @G-J where is the web server? Is it your local computer? Or sn actual server?

Comment: No the web server/database server is hosted on a shared server at Host Gator in the US. I am in Canada.

Comment: @MikeW I am curious... Since you seem to be the only person to get it working... Did you do anything different like specify a port number or anything else?

Comment: @G-J I was able to connect too. But both different servers though? If they are both on host gator then it should work server to server. They couldn't help you? Try specifying the port in the php connection of your app.

Comment: @G-J try using the IP address of the database server. Just do an ns lookup on the domain name. Just to eliminate DNS issue.

Comment: @PanamaJack Do you know of any free place I can place this code to test your suggestions outside of Host Gator. I would hate to keep bugging customers which have already been very patient

Comment: @G-J I meant try the ip in your code above instead of gjinternetsolutions.com for the connection

Comment: Ya... I get that... I just don't have anyway of testing outside of my local machine.